# Calculating date with 2 string without using any date or calendar class

Tags: java, date

The method receives 2 strings, e.g. `mon 2013-12-31 12:30:30 am`, and from those two strings I have to calculate the time between them. The time between the clock, `12:30:30 am`, is easy, but I can't find out how to get the correct time between the date. It has to be able to calculate it with bisextile year or "leap year". The problem that I'm having is mainly because the dates can be like this:

```
mon 2012-12-30 12:30:30 am, mon 2013-02-13 12:30:30 am.
```

The code has some sout's between just because I've been testing it and trying to make it work

```
public float calculateTime(String a, String b) {
    float time = 0;
    String indicatorA = a.substring(20, 22); //am and pm
    String indicatorB = b.substring(20, 22);
    int yearA = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0, 4));
    int monthA = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(5, 7));
    int dayA = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(8, 10));
    int hourA = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(11, 13));
    int minA = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(14, 16));
    int secA = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(17, 19));
    int yearB = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(0, 4));
    int monthB = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(5, 7));
    int dayB = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(8, 10));
    int hourB = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(11, 13));
    int minB = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(14, 16));
    int secB = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(17, 19));
    //get hours based on indicator am/pm
    int hourAI = hourIndicator(hourA, indicatorA);
    int hourBI = hourIndicator(hourB, indicatorB);
    //calculation
    if (yearA < (yearB-1)) {
        int days = 0;
        do {
            days += getDaysYear(yearA); //returns 366/365 days if it's a leap year
            yearA++;
        } while (yearA < (yearB - 1));
        time += 86400 * days; //turns time into seconds
        System.out.println(time/3600);
    }do{
    if(yearA == (yearB-1)){//if theere's only 1 year of difference
        int days = 0;
        if(monthA == monthB+11){//days when there's a month of diference //
            int daysA = getDaysMonth(monthA, yearA)- dayA;
            int daysBRest = getDaysMonth(monthB, yearB) -dayB;
            int daysB = getDaysMonth(monthB,yearB) -daysBRest;
            days += daysA + daysB;
        }
        if(monthA < monthB+11){//number of days between month A and B //
            do{
                days += getDaysMonth(monthA,yearA);
                monthA++;
            }while(monthA < monthB+11);
        }
        System.out.println(days);
        time += 86400 * days;
    }yearA++;
    }while(yearA <= (yearB-1));
    System.out.println(time/3600);     


    if(yearA == yearB){
    if (monthA < (monthB-1)) {
        int days = 0;
        do {
            days += getDaysMonth(monthA, yearA);
            monthA++;
        } while (monthA < (monthB - 1));
        time += 86400 * days;
    }}

    System.out.println(time/3600+"after month");


    if (dayA < dayB) {
        int days = 0;
        do {
            days += 1;
            dayA++;
        } while (dayA < (dayB - 1));
        time += days * 86400;
    }System.out.println(time/3600+"after day");

    if (hourAIndicator < hourBIndicator) {
        int hourD = hourBIndicator - hourAIndicator;
        time += hourD * 3600;
    }
    if (minA < minB) {
        int minD = minB - minA;
        time += minD * 60;
    }
    if (secA < secB) {
        int secD = secB - secA;
        time += secD;
    }
    System.out.println(time / 3600);
    return time;
}


private int hourIndicator(int hour, String indicator) {
    if ("am".equalsIgnoreCase(indicator)) {
        return hour;
    } else {
        return hour + 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use libraries for such an inherently complex stuff like date and time? I only agree with you when it is about java.util.Date which cannot be well used for calculating day differences. So at the moment Joda Time is the best alternative.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, ignore the day of the week.  Also, any year between 1901 and 2099 that's divisible by 4 is a leap year.  (If you need to go outside that range it's only slightly more complicated.)  (One way to go at it is that there are 365.25 days in a year, or a 4 year cycle of 1461 days.)

Comment: I really hope this is for learning and not for real product, otherwise writing date diff yourself is simply a bad idea

Comment: this is for a university project, they dont allow me to use gregorianCalendar, calendar or date, i actually had done that but had to change it :(

Comment: @HotLicks You're missing leap seconds!

Comment: I hope the point of the lesson is how hard it is to get date manipulation right.  I'd keep a bottle of aspirin handy, if I were you.

Comment: @Taylor - Most computer clock schemes ignore leap seconds.